# Quality of a VHS video with interlaced Yadif2 encoding and uploaded to YouTube is not so great

Tags: video, youtube

I have digitalized some old VHS videos, and they play back perfectly fine when I use the [Yadif2](http://Yadif2) in VLC player. But they don’t seem to play back well because of interlacing on YouTube.

Is there any way to make YouTube know that it should use this decoder when converting the video during the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that. You will have to convert the video yourself with the filter activated, and upload that.
See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en under "Frame Rate":

> Interlaced content should be deinterlaced before uploading. For
>   example, 1080i60 content should be deinterlaced to 1080p30, going from
>   60 interlaced fields per second to 30 progressive frames per second.

Handbrake is a free, open-source video encoder which can do this. Just select "Yadif" in the "Deinterlace" box, found on the "Filter" tab.

https://handbrake.fr/

Alternatively, you can *probably* use VLC itself to re-encode the video with the filter on. I have never tried it but I imagine it can be done.

Comment: :-( Thank you! I thought that YouTube was already prepared for such cases.

Comment: Yes it would be nice if there was such an option. I'd imagine the processing power required is just too prohibitive for them to offer it.